# How can I remove empty spaces which are both sides of banner?

Tags: android, admob

There are empty spaces right and left side of banner. How can I filled these? How can I expand the banner?

Take a look >>>

[image: image 1]

currently I'm using >>>>

[image: image 2]

Answer (score 3):

try this   use `ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"` insted of `ads:adSize="BANNER"`

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/string_banner_home_id"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER">

</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Comment: I add this >>>ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER">  but add is not showing on mobile.

Comment: did you get any error @awais

Comment: problem solved.